# Could not find a suitable constructor in play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin, how to resolve this issue?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, guice, ebean

Having the following error :

> ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:
>
> 1) Could not find a suitable constructor in play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
>     at play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.class(EbeanPlugin.java:23)
>     while locating play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin
>
> 1 error

Can Anyone help me with this I'm new to the playframework and cant really resolve such issue.

```
package models;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

import play.db.ebean.Model;


@MappedSuperclass
public class Bar extends Model {

    @Id
    public String id;

    public String name;
}
```

plugin.sbt

```
    // The Play plugin
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.2")

    // Web plugins
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.0.0")

    // Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for public fields
    // and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. Remove this
    // plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per project
    // basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

    // Play Ebean support, to enable, uncomment this line, and enable in your build.sbt using
    // enablePlugins(SbtEbean). Note, uncommenting this line will automatically bring in
    // Play enhancer, regardless of whether the line above is commented out or not.
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

Comment: I don't think this is enough information to answer the question. Can you include a partial module as well?

Comment: Your referring to the configuration files ?

Comment: I'm referring to your Guice [`Module`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/3.0/javadoc/com/google/inject/Module.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class does not have one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private

Try adding a zero-argument constructor which is not private, eg

```
public Bar() {}
```

Comment: Ah, my fault - I assumed that the class in your question was a simplified version of EbeanPlugin (which I can see it isn't) - could you update your question with the guice config class which declares the EbeanPlugin component?

Comment: I don't think I have created a Guice config class yet, but I added the component in the plugins.sbt

Comment: I posted the  plugins.sbt